# syntax-parameter pointing to a syntax-pattern-variable?

Tags: macros, racket, hygiene

The `syntax-parameterize` is commonly used in conjunction with `make-rename-transformer` so that the syntax-parameter `p` behaves as an alias for another identifier:

```lisp
#lang racket

(require racket/stxparam)
(define-syntax-parameter p #f)

(define-syntax (test-1-p stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ body)
     #'(let ([tmp 123])
         (syntax-parameterize ([p (make-rename-transformer #'tmp)])
           body))]))
(test-1-p p) ;; prints 123
```

The code above works well, as `tmp` is an identifier bound by `let`. If however I try to make `p` an alias for the pattern variable `tmp` bound by `with-syntax`, then it does not work as expected:

```lisp
#lang racket

(require racket/stxparam)
(define-syntax-parameter p #f)

(define-syntax (test-2-p stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ body)
     #'(with-syntax ([tmp #'(foo 123)])
         (syntax-parameterize ([p (make-rename-transformer #'tmp)])
           body))]))
(test-2-p #'p) ;; gives #'p, instead of #'(foo 123)
```

If instead I declare a `p-unhygienic` syntax, and bind it to `(make-rename-transformer #'tmp)`, then it works fine:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define-syntax (test-3-p stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ body)
     #`(with-syntax ([tmp #'(foo 123)])
         (define-syntax #,(syntax-local-introduce #'p-unhygienic)
           (make-rename-transformer #'tmp))
         body)]))
(test-3-p #'p-unhygienic) ;; gives #'(foo 123), as expected
```

How can I create a hygienic alias for a pattern variable using `syntax-parameterize` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting case, I expected the same thing you did. This might be either a bug somewhere or a limitation; I'm not sure. Either way, the [`define-rename-transformer-parameter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxparam.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstxparam..rkt%29._define-rename-transformer-parameter%29%29) form is provided as a workaround.

The initial value of a rename-transformer-parameter must be a rename-transformer, so you can use a `p-init` identifier with `#f` as the transformer binding.

```
(define-syntax p-init #f)
(define-rename-transformer-parameter p (make-rename-transformer #'p-init))
```

In context:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/stxparam)
(define-syntax p-init #f)
(define-rename-transformer-parameter p (make-rename-transformer #'p-init))

(define-syntax (test-2-p stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ body)
     #'(with-syntax ([tmp #'(foo 123)])
         (syntax-parameterize ([p (make-rename-transformer #'tmp)])
           body))]))
(test-2-p #'p) ; #<syntax:10:28 (foo 123)>
```

Comment: This is no bug, though it *is* a limitation. The documentation for `syntax-parameterize` states that “If `expr` produces a `make-rename-transformer` result, then `id` can be used as a macro that expands to a use of the target identifier, but `syntax-local-value` of `id` does not produce the target’s value.” I’m not totally sure why this limitation exists, but it would be interesting to find an explanation. The paper on syntax parameters does not seem to mention it. My guess is that syntax parameters themselves use an indirection that makes them incompatible with `syntax-local-value` directly.

Comment: In that case would it be `syntax`'s job to look through syntax-parameters just as it would through rename-transformers?

Comment: I don’t think so. Personally, if it’s anything’s job to handle this properly, I would think it would be `syntax-local-value`, since otherwise every single macro that uses `syntax-local-value` would need to also add special handling for syntax parameters. Of course, due to the way syntax parameters are implemented in Racket while `syntax-local-value` is implemented in C, that might be complicated, but it seems like there needs to be some better cooperation here.